# C# DataGridView update readonly column value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a datagridview, and it loads information from db. However, at run time, I want to allow a user to update a cell(which is readonly by default) but I am not able to do this, I need to do this because all the changes are saved in db but if I reload it it, some color style etc will be gone, therefore I want to only reload from db at request and make a change to the text of a read only col, please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the column read only? You can change that setting in the interface builder option and then add an event handler for it.

Comment: Interface builder option? can you please elaborate

Comment: Added a winforms tag.  Since datagridview I assum winforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the actual  `Question` of the user

I have a column in datagridview, which by default(`I dont set it readonly anywhere in code`) readonly. It is coming from a `dataset which gets data from a stored procedure`, this particular field is a calculated one, `so there is no column in the table for it`. All other fields which are in table I can manipulate, `except for this one`. I need to (for only display purposes in datagridview) change this columns value at run time which is causing a readonly error

This is the `Answer` which solved the user issue.

After you have read the data from dataset, the column for which it is saying read-only, try doing this - `ds.Tables[0].Columns["Your New Column"].ReadOnly = false;`

`Read the comments below for more clarity please.`

**Ignore the answer & code below because the actual question of the user is in the comments below which I have written above. User should modify his question. Its totally wrong and misleading**

Add a Winforms Project, Drop a DataGridView and a Button. Add a click Handler to the Button.

Add a column in DataGridView and name the `DataProperty` of the column as "Name" in the Designer. Mark it as `Read-Only`. The column DataPropertyName must match with fields in database. `I have a class called Books with a Property called Name`. Hence it should be called `Name` in this case.

Copy Paste the code below and Hit F5.

`Click the Button to update the read-only column value.`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
            books.Add(new Book() { Name = "C#" });

            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = books;
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1[0,0].Value = "Winforms";
        }
   }

    public class Book
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DataGridView Designer Code for Reference:-**

```
// 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.Column1});
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(42, 91);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(270, 157);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Column1
            // 
            this.Column1.DataPropertyName = "Name";
            this.Column1.HeaderText = "Name";
            this.Column1.Name = "Column1";
            this.Column1.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: I think its not the case in my question, my data source is a dataset returned from data base, and its a stored procedure that is returning data, this particular field is not even it db table, its a calculated field,therefore there is no table directly behind this....

Comment: You should frame your question properly then. You should provide information on how are you binding the data. Nobody can magically think of what you are doing. You have clearly said this - `I have a datagridview, and it loads information from db. However, at run time, I want to allow a user to update a cell(which is readonly by default) but I am not able to do this, I need to do this because all the changes are saved in db but if I reload it`.  So, my sample exactly depicts what you have asked.

Comment: Don't get upset..:-) Let me try again.
my question is I have a column in datagridview, which by default(I dont set it readonly anywhere in code) readonly. It is coming from a dataset which gets data from a stored procedure, this particular field is a calculated one, so there is no column in the table for it. 
All other fields which are in table I can manipulate, except for this one. I need to (for only display purposes in datagridview) change this columns value at run time which is causing a readonly error, hope this is clearer

Comment: What is the error ? How are you binding this field ? I would suggest to update your question and if possible please post the `code snippet` too.

Comment: After you have read the data from dataset, the column for which it is saying read-only, try doing this - `ds.Tables[0].Columns["Your New Column"].ReadOnly = false;`

Comment: Wonderfull, that did it. Thanks a bunch Angshuman...

Comment: Please modify your question. This will `mislead` anybody who reads this. I will add my answer as this to your question.